# How to dynamically set prefetch count RabbitMq

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

It is possible to set prefetch count param dynamically?  Here its what  I wanted to achieve. I have service which is queue subscriber. I have mechanism which is observing service resources like processor usage, RAM etc. This mechanism will send notification to service when this resources will be used to much. So when this notification comes I like to stop retrieving messages from queue. It could be done by unsubscribing from queue but it will be efficient?  It is possible to set prefetch count to 1 dynamically when this notification comes? If no, how to achieve this kind of thing? I am using C# and MasstTransit as servicebus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny you should ask, there is actually a very specific unit test that does just that very thing:

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/master/tests/MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Tests/SetPrefetchCount_Specs.cs

Comment: Updated link: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/master/tests/MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Tests/SetPrefetchCount_Specs.cs

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to stop consuming all messages is to stop the bus. Remember that sending messages still works even when the bus is stopped. To start receiving messages again you just need to start the bus.

Manipulating prefetch count will not prevent consuming messages.

Good practice for the behaviour like you are describing is to use circuit breaker. However, you cannot trigger the circuit breaker from the outside, at least not for the one that is used in MassTransit (the one from GreenPipes). It will only trigger if certain failure threshold will be met over a specified period of time. You might also want to create your own version if you want. You can check how it is done in [GreenPipes](https://github.com/MassTransit/GreenPipes/tree/develop/src/GreenPipes/Filters/CircuitBreaker) to get the idea.